# Random normal variable probability

Tags: probability

I have the following problem that I originally did on a calculator and then tried doing again by hand, that I keep getting different results on.

```
Substrate concentration of influent to a reactor is normally distributed with mean = 0.3 and standard deviation = 0.06
a.) What is the probability that the value exceeds 0.25?
b.) What is the probability that the value is at most 0.1?
c.) How would you characterize the largest 5% of all concentration values?
```

Here is what I did by hand, I'm not sure if I did this correctly however.

a.) $P(x > .25) = P(z > \frac {.25-.3}{.06}) = P(z > -.8333) = P(z < .8333) = 0.99997 $

b.) $P(x < .10) = P(z < \frac {.1 - .3}{.06}) =  P(z < -3.333)  $

For parts a and b, if I use the calculator in stattrek I'm able to get P(x>.25) = .7976 and P(x <.1) = .00043 instead. Am I doing something wrong when working out the problem by hand?

For part c I'm not quite sure how to find with a calculator.

Using the following site I get .3987 when searching for the 95 percentile.
bayes.bgsu.edu/nsf_web/jscript/normal_cdf/normal_icdf.htm

Answer (score 0):

In part a, how do you get $P(z < .83333) = 0.99997$? The correct value of $P(Z < .83333)$ with a standard normal $Z$ agrees with the value you got by using the stattrek calculator. Furthermore, please do not write
\begin{equation}
P(x > .25) = \frac{.25 - .3}{.06}
\end{equation}
because these two quantities are not equal.

Comment: I got that from reading a chart. I'm not completely clear on how to read the charts so I wanted to check. As for part C, it is only asking for the 95 percentile correct? If so then that would be the right answer based off the calculator

Comment: The equalities in part (a) are now correct, except the last one - $P(z<.8333)$ is not $0.99997$ - you seem to be reading the chart wrong. In c) it is indeed asking about the 95th percentile. You obtain the answer by reversing the process in a,b ($0.95 = P(z<something) = P(x< ) etc.$